# Facebook Comments widget?

Tags: android, facebook-comments

i am following this tutorial

> https://www.androidhive.info/2016/09/android-adding-facebook-comments-widget-in-app/

to add a comments widget to posts in my Android Application, and it is working fine. User need to type in his/her email and password in order to leave a comment. My question is, since i am using this widget in my Android app, is there a way to perform the user login using the pre installed facebook app in the device, i mean is there a way to detect Facebook app installed on the device and use it to perform the Log in? 
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To check if your user has facebook installed:

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context c, String targetPackage) {
    PackageManager pm = c.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use these packages:

```
com.facebook.orca
com.facebook.katana
com.example.facebook
com.facebook.android
```

And check if he has by this function:

```
boolean hasPackage = isPackageInstalled(MainActivity.this, "com.facebook.katana");
```

Since he has(or not), the app installed you could use his credentials by using the Facebook SDK.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);    

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
```

You can read more of this in:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

To prevent SDK problems:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
}
```

code with a WebView using facebook api that may help you:

https://gist.github.com/nguyenkims/28f3dc9d2414c3184263fab52b93351e

Comment: Hello, i've already implemented user login vis Facebook SDK, but my problem is that the WebView is not aware of that the user is already logged in. I an using WebView to display FB Comments widget, i've added an image in the question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "WebView is not aware of that the user is already logged in" but I guess this something related to the android version you are using, I'll add a code that might fix this "unawareness" of the WebView.

Comment: I am using a WebView to display FB Comments plugin in my app. When i am trying to add new comment it ask me to login despite that i am already logged in via sdk

Comment: the comment button comes from the API?

Comment: Please check the link provided in the question